# How to fix Python Gekko APMoniter solver error in MINLP problem: Equation without an equality

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

i want to solve this MINLP problem.I have check carefully but it says

```
 @error: Equation Definition
 Equation without an equality (=) or inequality (>,<)
 true
 STOPPING...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\code\3_1.py", line 61, in <module>
    m.solve(disp=True)
  File "C:\{path}\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gekko\gekko.py", line 2140, in solve
    raise Exception(apm_error)
Exception: @error: Equation Definition
 Equation without an equality (=) or inequality (>,<)
 true
 STOPPING...
```

Please help me!

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
#Data
X1i = [8, 4, 8, 8]
Q1i_POT = [14365.35, 7182.17, 14364.35, 14364.35]
Q1i = [14365.35, 7182.17, 14364.35, 14364.35]
Q11= 14365.35

qi = [0.94, 0.92, 0.96, 0.98]
k1i = [5000, 1500, 4500, 3500]
v1i=[18, 15, 24, 30]
ci=[30000, 25000, 36000,28000]
hs=[5, 20, 50, 95, 145]
es=[5, 15, 30, 45, 50]
ks=[0,200, 150, 100, 50]
m_val=30
e1=5
alpha = 4*10**8
delta = 2
qa=0.95
#Decison variables 
# Assuming Ji is a list of 4 continuous decision variables
Ji = [m.Var(value=0.0, lb=0.0) for _ in range(4)]  

# Assuming X1i is a list of 4 continuous decision variables
X1i = [m.Var(value=0.0, lb=0.0, integer=True) for _ in range(4)]  

# X2, X3, X4, X5
Xs = [m.Var(value=0.0, lb=0.0, integer=True) for _ in range(2, 6)]  

# Assuming P is a continuous decision variable with a lower bound greater than 0
P = m.Var(value=0.0, lb=1e-5)  

Q1 = m.Intermediate(Ji[1] * Q11)
# Constraint 1
m.Equation(Q1 == m.sum([Ji[i] * Q1i[i] for i in range(4)]))
# Constraint 2
for i in range(4):
    m.Equation(alpha * P**(-delta) * Ji[i] * Q1i[i] <= Q1 * ci[i])
# Constraint 3
m.Equation(m.sum([Ji[i] * Q1i[i] * qi[i] for i in range(4)]) <= Q1 * qa)
# Constraint 8
m.Equation(m.sum([Ji[i] for i in range(4)]) <= m_val)

# Constraint 10
for i in range(4):
    m.Equation(Q1i[i] >= 0)

# Constraint: 12
m.Equation(P > 0)

# Objective function
m.Maximize(alpha * P**(1-delta) - (1/Q1) \
        * (alpha * P**(-delta) \
        * m.sum([Ji[i] * k1i[i] for i in range(4)]) + \
        e1/2 * m.sum([Ji[i] * (Q1i[i])**2 for i in range(4)]) + \
        alpha * P**(-delta) * m.sum([Ji[i] * Q1i[i] * v1i[i] \
        for i in range(4)])))

m.solve(disp=True)
```

I've tried pretty much everything. I've retyped the equations and doubled checked all the syntax with chatgpt. I've had the same error for 7 days and I am very stuck

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with Constraint 10:

```py
Q1i = [14365.35, 7182.17, 14364.35, 14364.35]

# Constraint 10
for i in range(4):
    m.Equation(Q1i[i] >= 0)
```

This evaluates to `True` four times because the elements of `Q1i` are Python `float` types instead of Gekko variables and all are greater than zero.

For troubleshooting, open the run directory with `m.open_folder()` and the model file `gk_model0.apm`. The model file shows the problem with the equations that are listed as `True`.

```
Equations
    v14=((v1)*(14365.35))
    v15=((v2)*(7182.17))
    v16=((v3)*(14364.35))
    v17=((v4)*(14364.35))
    i0=v18
    ((((((400000000)*(((v13)^(-2)))))*(v1)))*(14365.35))<=((i0)*(30000))
    ((((((400000000)*(((v13)^(-2)))))*(v2)))*(7182.17))<=((i0)*(25000))
    ((((((400000000)*(((v13)^(-2)))))*(v3)))*(14364.35))<=((i0)*(36000))
    ((((((400000000)*(((v13)^(-2)))))*(v4)))*(14364.35))<=((i0)*(28000))
    v19=((((v1)*(14365.35)))*(0.94))
    v20=((((v2)*(7182.17)))*(0.92))
    v21=((((v3)*(14364.35)))*(0.96))
    v22=((((v4)*(14364.35)))*(0.98))
    v23<=((i0)*(0.95))
    v24<=30
    True
    True
    True
    True
    v13>0
    v25=((v1)*(5000))
    v26=((v2)*(1500))
    v27=((v3)*(4500))
    v28=((v4)*(3500))
```

For MINLP problems, you'll also need to switch to the APOPT solver with `m.options.SOLVER=1`.